# Fixed background and scroll able text slider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a webpage with a fixed full-screen background image and text or content sliding up the fixed webpage when I scroll. Like how this website, https://tokoshie-bullet.com/ , has a fixed video or gif section, and the text and content scrolling up. I just need help with the basics on how to lay it out in HTML and the positions I might need to use for the selectors in CSS or if I have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use background for this, you just need to fix the position for the background elements. like:

```css
.content{
  height:500px;
  margin:50px 0;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.fixed{
z-index:-1;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:.5;
  bottom:0;
  left:0; 
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">fixed background</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

And using this link, you can learn how to hide your scrollbar: [LINK](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MzBBdm)

Answer (score 0):

The concept you might be looking for is called parallax scrolling. Hopefully this source can help you out. [W3Schools - Parallax Scrolling](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)